# How do I rename a file from a "word" to a variable?

Tags: android

How do I rename a text file from "savedfile.txt" to *variable* ".txt"?

The user enters text, saved in a string called *message*. Presses the save button. Right now, a file called savedfile.txt is generated. If I input 1234, I want my file to be called 1234.txt.

```
public void sendClick(View view) {
// TODO : RENAME FILE TO INPUT  VARIABLE
    File file = new File (path + "/savedfile.txt");
            String[] saveText =      String.valueOf(messages.getText()).split(System.getProperty("line.separator")    );
    messages.setText("");
    Save (file, saveText);

    String message = messages.getText().toString();
    writeLine("Saved ski #: " + message);
```

Comment: new File(path + "/" + input +".txt") ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `"/savedfile.txt"` you need a variable for the name.

```
File file = new File(path + "/" + message + ".txt")
```

Collect your input from the user. Check if it has a number, if it does then you store the filename as the numbers else you store the file name as *message.txt*. You need to add the *smarts* so that if user enters `"hello123"` you treat that accordingly.

Comment: Changed it to  File file = new File (path + "/" + message +".txt"); but **message** is giving me an error **android.R.id.message? ALT+ENTER**  it's like it wants to import a library... I just want **message** to be the name. Also, when I hover over it, says **Cannot resolve symbol message**.

Comment: It looks like it's called input. Input is a **input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);** it's basically a textbox... so that doesn't work...

Comment: It is what ever you want to name it: `message` or `input`. It is only a variable.